# Creating app extension that enables acting on highlighted text

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

In ios 8 new app extensions, is it possible to create an app extension that would enable performing an action on a highlighted text? Similar to how today the copy and select sub menus appear, would it be able to add another custom action?

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to what you have described could be accomplished with an Action type extension, which allows your extension to act on the user's current selected content (text, image, etc). However, you won't be able to populate your action in the copy/paste submenu, as iOS action extensions are limited to displaying an action sheet or modal view. This will be presented when a user makes a selection, taps the Share button, and selects your extension from the activity view controller. Read more in the [App Extensions Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensibilityPG.pdf) under "Action" (page 48).

Comment: I see, is it possible to do this in OSX though?